# Testing Controller routing, how to post data using HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to test routing to my Controller's methods. I've got the following unit test:

```
[Test]
public void POST_PlaylistItem_Should_route_to_PlaylistItemController_Create_method()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/PlaylistItem/");

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    var route = Helpers.RouteRequest(config, request);

    route.Controller.Should().Be<PlaylistItemController>();
    route.Action.Should().Be("Create");
}
```

I need to be able to POST content with the message so that my controller can make a decision between the two following signatures:

```
[HttpPost]
public PlaylistItemDto Create(PlaylistItemDto playlistItemDto)

[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<PlaylistItemDto> CreateMultiple(List<PlaylistItemDto> playlistItemDtos)
```

I was looking through some resources and I found an example for doing it using async + HttpClient, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#PostingResource, but I wasn't keen on overcomplicating my example with unfamiliar technology until I had the basics working. Using the HttpClient I wasn't able to easily send a message to the controller / it was acting as if a server isn't running.

Comment: The thing is, it's not the controller that will "make a decision between the two". It's ASP.NET Web API's routing infrastructure. Since you just configure (in App_Start) Web API's routing - and since without the HTTP context or the server architecture, nothing knows which method should be called - I'd say what you're really looking for is an integration test.

When we want to test that routing happens correctly, we just script (in wget or Selenium, or something) HTTP requests to a staging web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got it figured out. Note that I haven't converted to Attribute-based routing which is preferable, but this serves as a good starting example:

**Goal is to test that these two method signatures don't conflict / confuse Web API:**

```
[HttpPost]
public PlaylistItemDto Create(PlaylistItemDto playlistItemDto)

[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<PlaylistItemDto> CreateMultiple(List<PlaylistItemDto> playlistItemDtos)
```

In my WebApiConfig class:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Create",
    routeTemplate: "PlaylistItem",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "PlaylistItem",
        action = "Create"
    }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CreateMultiple",
    routeTemplate: "PlaylistItem/CreateMultiple",
    defaults: new
        {
            controller = "PlaylistItem",
            action = "CreateMultiple"
        }
);
```

This says that anything with just an action name of PlaylistItem will be routed to the Create action. Anything that is PlaylistItem/CreateMultiple will be routed to the CreateMultiple action.

Then, to check to see if this works:

```
[Test]
public void POST_PlaylistItem_Should_route_to_PlaylistItemController_Create_method()
{ 
    // setups
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/PlaylistItem/");

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // act
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    var route = Helpers.RouteRequest(config, request);

    // asserts
    route.Controller.Should().Be<PlaylistItemController>();
    route.Action.Should().Be("Create");
}

[Test]
public void POST_CreateMultiple_PlaylistItem_Should_route_to_PlaylistItemController_CreateMultiple_method()
{
    // setups
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/PlaylistItem/CreateMultiple");

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // act
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    var route = Helpers.RouteRequest(config, request);

    // asserts
    route.Controller.Should().Be<PlaylistItemController>();
    route.Action.Should().Be("CreateMultiple");
}
```

where RouteRequest comes from [Testing route configuration in ASP.NET WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851558/testing-route-configuration-in-asp-net-webapi)